# CSS (grid) : Reorder col element on mobile dynamically without template-areas

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, css-grid

I am trying to dynamically change the order of `<div>` on mobile without having to hardcode each `<div>` with a specific class to be then organised using `grid-template-areas`.

What I have right now :

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>
  <div class="f"></div>
</div>
```

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  grid-template-areas:  "a b"
                        "c d"
                        "e f";

  .a { grid-area: a; }
  .b { grid-area: b; }
  .c { grid-area: c; }
  .d { grid-area: d; }
  .e { grid-area: e; }
  .f { grid-area: f; }

  @media (max-width: 960px) {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-areas:  "a"
                            "c"
                            "e"

                            "b"
                            "d"
                            "f";
  }
}
```

The problem is that each time I need a new "row" I need to assign the new `grid-area` property to the corresponding col `<div>` and update the `template-areas` in the CSS file.

Example of what I have to do if I add a new row :

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  ...
  <div class="g"></div>
  <div class="h"></div>
</div>
```

```
.grid-container {
  ...
  grid-template-areas:  "a b"
                        "c d"
                        "e f"
                        "g h"; // NEW

  ...
  .g { grid-area: g; } // NEW
  .h { grid-area: h; } // NEW

  @media (max-width: 960px) {
      ...
      grid-template-areas:  "a"
                            "c"
                            "e"
                            "g"

                            "b"
                            "d"
                            "f"  // NEW
                            "h"; // NEW
  }
}
```

As you can see this is (obviously) not really a good solution as the row will be populated by an array of data so I have no idea of knowing how many row will there be.

**Is there a way to dynamically achieve this ?** :s #beMyHero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure I understand what you mean.

If want divided into two parts, can use `order` & `nth-child`

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);

  @media (max-width: 960px) {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      > div:nth-child(2n) {
        order: 1;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed!